# Test Method always assert

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my Rails Tests.
I have a Model News and a Model Tag, which have a HABTM Relationship
News Model:

```
 class News < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
  validate :has_tags?

  private

    # Validates presence of tags
    def has_tags?
      errors.add(:tags, ": News must have some tags.") if self.tags.blank?
    end
```

Test Model:

```
 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :news

  validates :name, presence: true
```

I wrote a Test for the has_tags validation:

```
 test "should be valid" do
    assert @news.valid?
  end

  test "news should have tags" do
    assert_not @news.tags.blank?
  end
```

My News Fixtures:

```
 news1:
  name: Newstest
  tags:
```

Tag Fixtures:

```
one:
  name: Music

two:
  name: Movie
```

When I run rake test:models, the two tests are failing, which is right.
And when I add a tag to the News Fixture and run the Test again, the test passes.

```
 news1:
    name: Newstest
    tags: one
```

But when I remove the Tag in the fixture and run rake test:models again, the tests are passing again.
How comes, that the Tests are true after removing the "one" tag.

To fix this I always must run `rake db:test:prepare` in the console.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a Rails test, your test fixture data is loaded into the test database.  It is not cleared unless you explicitly clear it (for instance, with `rake db:test:prepare`).  You can verify this by downloading the test database using a tool like SqliteBrowser and inspecting the data.

So, even though you are altering the test fixtures in between test runs, if you are not clearing the test database, your previous test data will still be present.

Comment: @Yoda not to my knowledge.  This is one reason I use `rspec`.  If you include `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` in rails_helper.rb, each test example is run as a separate transaction on a clean database.